# Finding probability in "at least " scenario

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose there is a grocery store with 3 branches, with the probability that KoolAid is present in store
A : 0.35
B: 0.55
C : 0.10

How can I find the probability that KoolAid will be present in at least 2 stores?

My idea so far:
Divide into 3 cases:

1. Present in A and B (not C)
2. Present in B & C (not A)
3. Present in A & C (not B)

I'm not sure how to calculate these however or if I'm missing a case?

Comment: If Koolaid is present in at least 2 stores, then you need to account for the time that it is present in all 3. You're very close though.

Comment: so for case 1 do I just do 0.35+0.55-0.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

Assuming the probabilities of KoolAid present in each store are independent then you can use the definition of independence on the three subcases you found plus another case that you missed (all store with KoolAid)

Comment: so for case 1 do I just do 0.35+0.55-0.10?

Comment: no you must multiply, and remember that it is not 0.1 for C because you have not C so you should do $0.35 \cdot 0.55 \cdot (1-0.1) $

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to find out that its present in 0 stores then I would simply do (1-0.35) * (1-.0.55) * (1-0.1) right

Comment: yes that's right!

Comment: Hi also, once I find probability for all 4 cases, do I add them or multiple them together? I was thinking I should add them

Comment: you have to add them because they are all disjoint events!